# How do I remove the right side spacing or padding in a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have the following drop-down menu spinner:

[image: 1]

I want to remove the right side spacing or padding that I have underlined in red. How do I do that? I still want the arrow to show up.

This is what I have for the `Spinner`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have complete control of a complex view like a spinner that contains multiple children views is to create your own, with your own adapter.
This will allow you to change the internal item structure. This includes adding pictures, alternating colors you name it.

Here is a link to an article that will get you started.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-custom-spinner-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

To remove the space you can align the menu items to the right using `android:gravity="right"`. That was the items will be right aligned and the space won't be visible

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="43dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="right"                   //add this line
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```